# Generate code at runtime

Tags: python, django

I need to generate at run time the model below base on the from values.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to acheive, but the issue is clear i.e. [field.value]...

```
def import_data(form, *args, **kw):
    class ContactCSVModel(CsvModel):  
        for field in form:
           [field.value] =  CharField()

         class Meta:
            delimiter = ","
            dbModel = Contact
            update = {'keys': ["mobile", "group"]}

      return ContactCSVModel.import_data(*args, **kw)
```

So above code would look like this after it was generated (if it was typed static code)....

```
def import_data(form, *args, **kw):
    class ContactCSVModel(CsvModel):  

        first_name = CharField()
        mobile = CharField()
        last_name = CharField()

         class Meta:
            delimiter = ","
            dbModel = Contact
            update = {'keys': ["mobile", "group"]}
  return ContactCSVModel.import_data(*args, **kw)
```

How can I get `[field.value]` to work in the way I need it to? I've had looked at things like setattr() but I don't think that is what I'm after.

Forms.py for reference...

```
COL_CHOICES = [
    ('NONE', 'No Import'),
    ('first_name', 'First Name'),
    ('last_name', 'Last Name'),
    ('company', 'Company'),
    ('mobile', 'Mobile Number'),
    ('email', 'Email Address'),
    ]


class ConfiguratorForm(forms.Form):
    col1 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=COL_CHOICES, initial='first_name')
    col2 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=COL_CHOICES, initial='first_name')
    col3 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=COL_CHOICES, initial='first_name')
    col4 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=COL_CHOICES, initial='first_name')
    col5 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=COL_CHOICES, initial='first_name')
```

Comment: Are you trying to say that you don't know the CSV fields before runtime?

Comment: I'm letting the user assign what column the fields belong to. I'll add my form so it makes more sense.

Comment: `setattr(ContactCSVModel, field.value, CharField())` is the construct you're looking for.

Comment: @millimoose  Thanks, I did try that but got the error "free variable 'ContactCSVModel' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope"

Comment: I also tired setattr(CsvModel, field.value, CharField()) but got the error: "attribute name must be string, not 'instancemethod'"

Comment: @Spike You need to do that *after* defining the class. Also, use `value()` maybe? I'm not going to read the Django docs for you, it's up to you to get the field name correctly, I'm just telling you how to dynamically add it.

Comment: @millimoose Ok getting it now, I tried this and it seems to work:  setattr(CsvModel, field.value(), CharField())

Comment: @millimoose you want to add an answer so I can accept? seems to be working for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add fields to the class object after it's constructed:

```
def import_data(form, *args, **kw):
    class ContactCSVModel(CsvModel):

         class Meta:
            # ...

    for field in form:
        setattr(ContactCSVModel, field.value(), CharField())

    return ContactCSVModel.import_data(*args, **kw)
```

Comment: If `CsvModel` is a `django.db.Model` subclass setting fields this way might not work correctly - there's a lot of things happening with models fields in `django.db.Model`'s metaclass, cf https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/db/models/base.py (`ModelBase.__new__` )

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Hm, I didn't really know there's a metaclass involved. Constructing the whole thing at runtime is probably the sane option then.

Answer (score 4):

The `class` statement is syntactic sugar for `type(name, bases, dict)` so you can just build a dictionnary of your dynamic model attributes and pass it to type, ie:

```
def import_data(form, *args, **kw):
    class Meta:
        delimiter = ","
        dbModel = Contact
        update = {'keys': ["mobile", "group"]}
    clsmap = dict((field.value(), CharField()) for field in form)
    clsmap["Meta"] = Meta
    ContactCsvModel = type("ContactCsvModel", (CsvModel,), clsmap)         
    return ContactCSVModel.import_data(*args, **kw)
```

Comment: Interesting, what would I do in ContactCSVModel class, just 'pass'?

Comment: @Spike You don't write the class in this case, it's created dynamically on the second-to-last line of the answer.

Comment: Reread the code : you _dont_ have a `class` statement at all - the class is created by the call to `type`, not by a class statement.